# How to realize the "undo" functionality in CQ5 Rich Text Editor with a button?

Tags: aem

Using `CQ Rich Text Editor`, I can undo the editing with `strg + z`. How to connect this functionality with a button? In other words where to find the javascript which is responsible for `undo` functionality?
[image]

Comment: where do you wish to use this button?? In rte or in some other component? What purpose it is expected to serve?

Comment: in RTE. It aims to facilitate the work of the redactor. Not everyone know about "Strg + Z"

Comment: Correct. But then you already have an undo button in RTE, why do you want to create a new one?

Comment: My RTE consist of a table only and it does not have "undo-button"

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're creating a RTE with TABLE only features and you also need a Undo button?

Answer (score 2):

In your RTE plugins (in the xml file), use:

```
<table
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    features="*"/>
<undo
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    features="*"/>
```

Hope this solves your problem.

For more info check [here](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/configuring_rich_text_editor.html#History%20Size%20for%20Undo/Redo)